# git gui cannot start because of bad version number

Tags: linux, git, tcl, git-gui

I'm running an ancient Ubuntu and after the automatic update, `git-gui` stopped working and complains instead:

```
Error in startup script: expected version number but got "1.7.0-"
    while executing
"package vsatisfies $_git_version 1.7.0-"
    (file "/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-gui" line 1)
```

My "fix" was to revert `/usr/lib/git-core/git-gui` as follows

```
1286c1286
< if {[package vsatisfies $_git_version 1.7.0]} {
---
> if {[package vsatisfies $_git_version 1.7.0-]} {
1542c1542
<   if {[package vsatisfies $::_git_version 1.6.3]} {
---
>   if {[package vsatisfies $::_git_version 1.6.3-]} {
```

The sad thing is that after the next update it happened again. This problem seems to be rare, the only relevant link from this year I found was this a deleted question on SO. I'm using `git 2.0.0`, `tclsh 8.4`.

Comment: The `package vsatisfies` syntax was extended in 8.5, so you are hit by the incompatible syntax. And yes, no wonder it is rare, Tcl 8.4. has reached the end of support since quite a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a change to the package version number satisfaction logic in Tcl 8.5 which allowed it to support more complex version expressions. It appears that `git-gui` is using this extended syntax (unnecessarily as it happens) and as such, you're going to be fighting this fight with it *every time you update it* until you upgrade your system to have Tcl 8.5.

This is recommended anyway; Tcl 8.4 is out of support, there will be *no* future releases of it, and the changes to the package version logic will not be backported.

---

There is a bug in the `git-gui` code; it should say in itself somewhere (probably at the top of its main script) exactly this:

```
package require Tcl 8.5
```

since it uses functionality from Tcl 8.5. That wouldn't fix things for you, but would tell you the correct thing you need to do about it.

Comment: I'm still using Ubuntu 10.04 and it looks like Tcl 8.4 is the proper version for my ancient OS. I'm already used to reverting `/usr/lib/git-core/git-gui`. If only there were anything better in the new Linuxes which would motivate me to go through the upgrade hassle.